# JSONEncoder and PropertyListEncoder don't conform to Encoder?

Tags: swift, encoding, codable, decodable

I am trying to write an `Encoder`/`Decoder` pair that wraps an given `Encoder`/`Decoder`. The goal of this wrapper is to successfully handle cyclic references (which neither `JSONEncoder` nor `PropertyListEncoder` do), and delegate the actual encoding/decoding to the wrappded encoder.

I was surprised to learn that neither `JSONEncoder` nor `PropertyListEncoder` conform to `Encoder` and similarly, their `Decoder` counterparts don't conform to `Decoder`!

This seems bizarre. If these two types don't conform, then what's the point of the `Encoder` protocol? Looking at the [source](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift), I can see that internally, `_JSONEncoder` conforms, but it's `fileprivate`.

So is there no hope? Is there really no way to generically wrap an `Encoder` like `JSONENcoder` or `PropertyListEncoder`?

Comment: The problem is that not all encoders/decoders may share the same top-level interface for encoding/decoding; for example I recently knocked together [an encoder that can encode a type into a URL query](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/d1cabdf19cce90ca8458da9294562542). The `Encoder` and `Decoder` protocols present a generic interface for types to encode/decode themselves to/from. You could absolutely define `protocol BinaryFormatEncoder { func encode<T : Encodable>(_ value: T) throws -> Data }` and conform `JSONEncoder` and `PropertyListEncoder` to it though.

Comment: Although that being said, I'm not actually sure that'll help you with your goal as (unless I'm missing something) it doesn't really give you a way to walk through the hierarchy of a given type. One possible solution would be to define a wrapper type, e.g `CyclicReferenceEncoder<T : Encodable> : Encodable`, which you can then use with e.g `JSONEncoder.encode(CyclicReferenceEncoder(value))`.

Comment: Then in the the wrapper type's `encode(to:)`, you could call `.encode(to:)` on the wrapped value by passing in your *custom encoder* which would probably keep a reference to `Encoder` passed to the wrapper (e.g `JSONEncoder`'s internal `Encoder`), which you could then manage the encoding with. Annoyingly, I think that's probably the best you'll manage as I don't believe there's another way to extract the internal encoder for `JSONEncoder`/`PropertyListEncoder`.

Comment: @Hamish That's actually pretty much what I was looking to do. My initial idea was to intercept all the calls to what turns out to be _JSONEncoder, but I guess `JSONEncoder` is all I have to work with. If i could intercept the call to encode `Codable` instances, that's where I would be able to insert logic to check for cyclic references and serialize them appropriately

Comment: This actually gave me an idea for customising how individual types are encoded/decoded to/from a payload (https://github.com/hamishknight/CustomCodable/blob/master/Demo/main.swift). One annoying thing however is that decoders have to opt-in to the functionality, as there's no real way to get the underlying `Decoder` without doing a "dummy decode" :/