# Hack a module map to expose fileprivate constructs?

Tags: json, swift, encoder, decoder, module-map

I'm implementing my own JSON encoder/decoder, à la Swift's `Encoder` & `Decoder` protocols.

The thing is, I only want to override a small subset of the functionality already provided by `JSONEncoder` in Foundation. `JSONEncoder`, contrary to its name, is not an actual Swift `Encoder`. Instead, it [wraps](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift) a fileprivate class `_JSONEncoder`, which implements all the required `Encoder` functions.

To write my own customized encoder, I could either:

- Write my own JSON encoder from scratch.
- Copy-paste and modify `_JSONEncoder` from the source itself.

Neither are particularly appealing solutions. Writing my own encoder is an arduous and daunting task, and I have no doubt that it will be riddled with bugs. Copy-pasting `_JSONEncoder`, on the other hand, forces me to awkwardly check and port fixes each time there's an update to the original source file.

I'd rather just have `_JSONEncoder` exposed, and wrap its `Encoder`-related functions while injecting my own code as necessary.

Comment: Even if that were possible: A private class is an implementation detail of the Foundation library and may change with a new release, which makes your approach fragile.

Comment: @MartinR: I understand, and it's an acceptable compromise to me for now.

Comment: You could write a wrapper `Encoder` by making a dummy `Encodable`, passing that off to `JSONEncoder`, and then having your custom encoder wrap the `Encoder` you get back during encoding (related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48123983/2976878).

Comment: @Hamish: Hadn't thought about that, seems like it could work. Thanks!