# Generic Decoders in Swift 4

Tags: swift, generics, swift4, codable

Currently I'm using this code to handle decoding some data:

```
private func parseJSON(_ data: Data) throws -> [ParsedType] 
{
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let parsed = try decoder.decode([ParsedType].self, from: data)
    return parsed
}

private func parsePlist(_ data: Data) throws -> [ParsedType] 
{
    let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
    let parsed = try decoder.decode([ParsedType].self, from: data)
    return parsed
}
```

Is there a way to create a generic method that ties all this repeated code together?

```
private func parse(_ data: Data, using decoder: /*Something*/) throws -> [ParsedType]
{
    let parsed = try decoder.decode([ParsedType].self, from: data)
    return parsed
}
```

Comment: [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123983/jsonencoder-and-propertylistencoder-dont-conform-to-encoder?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment83232091_48123983) might be helpful; in short, not all decoders may share the same top-level interface for decoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the swift stdlib for [JSONEncoder](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift) and [PropertyListDecoder](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/PlistEncoder.swift) you will see that they both share a method

```
func decode<T: Decodable >(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T
```

So you could create a protocol that has said method and conform both decoders to it:

```
protocol DecoderType {
    func decode<T: Decodable >(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T
}

extension JSONDecoder: DecoderType { }
extension PropertyListDecoder: DecoderType { }
```

And create your generic parse function like so:

```
func parseData(_ data: Data, with decoder: DecoderType) throws ->  [ParsedType] {
    return try decoder.decode([ParsedType].self, from: data)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's certainly a great way to go, but I don't like the boilerplate involved in having to extend each Decoder type.

Comment: @XmasRights you want to use two classes that share nothing in common excepting a couple of methods with the same signature, you have to write some code to unify those two classes.

Answer (score 0):

Decodable+Generic.swift

```
import Foundation

// Generic decode method for Decodable
func decode<T: Decodable>(data: Data) throws -> T {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
}
```

Decodable+GenericTests.swift

```
import XCTest
@testable import YourProject

class Decodable_EncodableTests: XCTestCase {
    func testDecodableEncodable() {
        struct User: Decodable, Encodable {
            let name: String
            let sex: String
        }
        let json = """
        {
            "name": "Ronaldo",
            "sex": "Female"
        }
        """.data(using: .utf8)!

        do {
            // When
            let name = "Ronaldo"
            let sex = "Female"
            let user: User = try decode(data: json)

            // Then
            XCTAssertEqual(user.name, name)
            XCTAssertEqual(user.sex, sex)

        } catch let error {
            XCTFail(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.